# Preventing form from submitting multiple times

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I've attempted using vuejs to create a form which ultimately uses [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to do a POST request. However, the submit button does not disable during form validation. I am trying to prevent the user from submitting multiple times…

Code to reproduce:

```
<div>
    <form @submit.prevent="checkForm">
    <input
        type="submit"
        :disabled="submitting"
        :value="value"
    >
</div>
```

Where:

```
checkForm( e ) {
    this.submitting = true;
    this.value = 'Submitting';

    // Form Validation

    this.submitting = false;
    this.value = 'Submit';
}
```

Comment: Does the button text change when you submit the form? If not, you should probably be using computed properties returning the values of `this.submitting` and `this.value`.

Comment: No, the text does not change. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: You can't really prevent the user from doing anything with client side code.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html is the documentation for computed properties

Comment: Simple example: `computed: {
    disabledSubmit: function () {
      return this.submitting
    },
    buttonText: function() {
       return this.submitting ? 'Submitting' : 'Submit';
    }
  }`

Comment: This [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/EemLgx?editors=1010) shows your code should already work. Can you show more of your `checkForm` code?

Comment: Are you sure that the code is not simply "too fast" and you don't see the disabling of a button? Try removing `this.submitting = false;` . Also if you want to be 100% certain, add `if (this.submitting === true) return;` into the method.

Comment: @tony19 That is a callback which does work, but if you were to replace the timeout with a heavy calculation (say `for(let i = 0; i < 100000; i += 1)`), it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Danijel I have thought that too, but I am performing an API call right after the form validation, but when I click on the button multiple times, I end up calling the API multiple times

Comment: But that heavy calculation isn't what you're actually doing, right? You're using Axios to make a request, which has a `then` callback. That's where you would set `this.value` and `this.submitting`.

Comment: @tony19 Ah, you're right. I'll try that when I get the chance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments, it sounds like you're making an asynchronous request (in `axios.post()`) and immediately setting `this.submitting` and `this.value` without awaiting the result of the network request, similar to this example:

```js
checkForm( e ) {
  this.submitting = true;
  this.value = 'Submitting';

  axios.post('https://foo');

  this.submitting = false;
  this.value = 'Submit';
}
```

Since `axios.post()` is asynchronous (i.e., returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)), the lines that follow are executed before the `POST` request even occurs. You can either move those settings into the [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) callback of `axios.post()`:

```js
checkForm( e ) {
  this.submitting = true;
  this.value = 'Submitting';

  axios.post('https://foo').then(() => {
    this.submitting = false;
    this.value = 'Submit';
  });
}
```

Or you can use [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description) like this:

```js
async checkForm( e ) {
  this.submitting = true;
  this.value = 'Submitting';

  await axios.post('https://foo');

  this.submitting = false;
  this.value = 'Submit';
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/oPWdJw?editors=1010)